# Javascript slideshow clickable buttons

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm looking for a little help with my javascript slideshow, for which the code was used from a tutorial on the internet. I want to basically make it so when you mouse over it stops the image from changing. Also, i'd like to have two buttons at the bottom of the slideshow such as the image below.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/slideshowexample.jpg/

```
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/slide1.jpg" name="slide" />
<script>
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 5 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",5000)
}
slideit()
//--></div></script>
```

Thanks in advance,
Nick.

Comment: Hmm... I think the tutorial you followed was written in the 90s, it does almost everything the wrong way.

Comment: `//if browser does not support the image object, exit.` yup, that's pretty old. you should consider using something more up to date and flexible, maybe [link](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/) or even [link](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) - i don't think you're going to get anyone to write your slideshow for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are just doing this as an exercise to learn more about JavaScript, a better option than a homegrown slideshow would probably be to use a DOM library.  There's a pretty good tutorial on creating a [slideshow with jQuery](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/) at SixRevisions.

There are also a number of pre-built slideshow plugins for the various DOM libraries jQuery [has a bunch](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/slide).

If you were to continue using your current code, to create the pause on mouseover you would first need to create a variable and store the result of `setTimeout()` in it.

```
var timer;
timer = setTimeout(slideIt, 5000);  // note I just passed the function name instead
                                    // of quoting an invocation.  Using "slide()"
                                    // creates an unnecessary eval() call.
```

You could then use the `timer` variable to call `clearTimeout()` in a mouseover event you attach to the the image.  You would also need to attach a mouseout event to call `setTimeout()` again to restart the slide show.  That said, this is a situation you should really be using `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`.

You don't need the `<!--` and `//-->` unless your expect you code to be running in ancient browsers like Netscape 1.0 and IE 2; all modern browsers understand JavaScript and don't need that hack to hide JS.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I actually require the code for a web design project rather than self education regarding javascript. Your answer is much appreciated Useless Code, however i wouldn't have a clue how to implement any of the suggestions you've made - but none-the-less, thanks.

Comment: Then you would probably be better off using a pre-built solution like the ones @changokun mentioned or using a more modern tutorial like the one I linked to.